# Find probability of 4th smallest number?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Seven numbers are selected from the numbers (1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 17) without replacement. What is the probability that the 4th smallest number is 9? I'm not sure if I'm getting the correct answer, but this is what I have so far:

The set of numbers less than 9 is (1, 2, 4, 8) and we need to choose 3 of them, so we have ${4 \choose 3}=4$ possibilities. This uses 3 of the 7 positions available.

Then a 9 has to be selected for one of the positions as well, so there are only 3 positions left.

Finally, since there are no repetitions the only numbers left are 10, 11, 15, and 17 and there are 3 positions available, which means there are 4 x 3 x 2 = 24 possibilities for the final 3 positions.

So there are a total of 4 x 1 x 4 x 3 x 2 = 96 ways of selecting numbers so that 9 is the 4th smallest digit.

The total number of ways to select 7 digits without repetitions is 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 = 181440.

Therefore, the probability that the 4th smallest number is 9 is 96 / 181400. Is this correct, or did I go wrong somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The set of numbers less than 9 is (1, 2, 4, 8) and we need to choose 3 of them, so we have 4 choose 3 which is 4. This uses 3 of the 7 positions available.

Good.

> Then a 9 has to be selected for one of the positions as well, so there are only 3 positions left.
>
> Finally, since there are no repetitions the only numbers left are 10, 11, 15, and 17 and there are 3 positions available, which means there are 4 x 3 x 2 = 24 possibilities for the final 3 positions.

Why are you considering order here, but not for $\{1,2,4,8\}$? You just need to choose $3$ numbers from $\{10,11,15,17\}$, so it is still $4$ choose $3$.

> So there are a total of 4 x 1 x 4 x 3 x 2 = 96 ways of selecting numbers so that 9 is the 4th smallest digit.

This should be $\binom{4}{3} \binom{4}{3}$.

> The total number of ways to select 7 digits without repetitions is 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 = 181440.

You need to divide this by $7!$ because you are just choosing 7 numbers and do not care about their arrangement.

Comment: Ok thanks. So the correct probability is 4/9. I think I'm just a bit confused about when to use combinations instead of permutations.

Comment: @peppy In general, when computing probabilities, it actually doesn't matter whether you use combinations or permutations _as long as you remain consistent and don't use both_. One way might be easier and/or more intuitive than the other though