# Find the probability that number 9 is third smallest number.

Tags: probability

Number 1 through 14 are given and 5 numbers are selected at random. Find probability that number 9 is third smallest number. Using the explanation here: [Find probability of 4th smallest number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939711/find-probability-of-4th-smallest-number)

The solution is coming out to be absurd. So here is my approach.

There are 8 numbers less than 9, so choose 2 numbers from this set. ${8 \choose 2}$.

Fix number 9. ${1 \choose 1}$

Choose 2 numbers from rest of the numbers. ${5 \choose 2}$

So for the event. Number of elements = ${8 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1}{5 \choose 2}$

Sample space ${14 \choose 5}$

Probability $$p = \frac{{8 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}}{{14 \choose 5}}$$
Also, choosing number 9 from 14 numbers = $\frac{1}{14}$

So required probability $P=\frac{p}{14}$

Comment: The value you received of $p=\dfrac{\binom{8}{2}\binom{5}{2}}{\binom{14}{5}}$ was correct.  You did not need to multiply this by an additional $\frac{1}{14}$ and doing so made your answer incorrect.

Comment: I went ahead with that part because my solution was incorrect. So I thought I must be missing this one. My answer doesn't match even if I remove 1/14 factor.

Comment: And what does the supposedly "correct" solution that you are comparing it to look like?  They might be the same value but just written in different ways, or it might give us a clue as to a typo or forgotten assumption that was missing from your question.  Like for instance that you are selecting the numbers with repetition as opposed to without repetition

Comment: Yeah.. Its correct, calculation mistake!. I guess I didn't had confidence that I will solve this problem and didn't check calculation, so assumed and went ahead with blunder. What about the link that I shared. Is that solution correct? Because the sample space there is 7! which I think is incorrect.

Comment: No.  the sample space used by angryavian in the solution posted to the linked problem is of size $\binom{9}{7}$.  The comment about $7!$ there was about correcting the OP's mistaken calculations about the size of the sample space and was saying that to correct the OP's attempt the denominator needed to be divided by an additional factor of $7!$, not that the size of the sample space was $7!$.

Comment: In the end however, the sample space can be however large or however small you like so long as it is consistent and adequately describes the problem.  You could use permutations instead if you like, but in doing so you would be accounting for order as being relevant in the sample space so you should treat order as being relevant for counting the events too.  Certain choices will make calculations easier, and you often should try to use a sample space which has each outcome being equally likely as it allows you to use counting techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct all the way to
$$
p = \frac{{8 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}}{{14 \choose 5}}={20\over 143}\approx 0.14.
$$